If $f:X \to Y$ induces isomorphism in cohomology, then it induces isomorphism in homology
Let $f:X \to Y$ and $G$ a group (I'm interested specifically in the case $G=\mathbb{Q}$) such that $f^\ast:H^q(X;G) \to H^q(Y;G)$  is an isomorphism for all $q$.
It it true that $f_*:H_q(X;G) \to H_q(Y;G)$ for all $q$?
I know that some sort of converse is true: if $f:X \to Y$ induces $f_*:H_q(X) \to H_q(Y)$ isomorphisms for all $q$, than by the Universal Coefficent Theorem we have that $f^\ast:H^q(X;G) \to H^q(Y;G)$ are isomorphism for all $q$ and for all $G$ groups.
In this other question I got a comment from Qiaochu Yuan that suggested that a map induces an isomorphism on rational cohomology iff it induces an isomorphism on rational homology, suggesting that it follows from the Universal Coefficient Theorem, but I don't know how.
Any help is appreciated!

Did you search the site beforehand?

Universal coefficient theorem has too many meanings, but here is a relevant one

@FShrike Of course I searched the site beforehand. The question you linked assumed that there is isomorphism in cohomology for every coefficient ring, which is not my question.

Ah I didn’t catch that (for all) quantifier, apologies for not reading too closely. So your claim is true for field coefficients; if you had a “general” (PID) ring coefficient then you would need a finiteness assumption I think cf. the different UCT shown in the other link

Ah, but of course Abelian groups are Z-modules and Z is a PID so if you only cared about this case, a finite type assumption is all you need - I think

I would comment but I don't have enough reputation.
The UCT tells us we have these short exact sequences of $A$-modules (with $A$ a PID):
$$0\rightarrow Ext^1(H_{i-1}(X; A), G)\rightarrow H^{i}(X; G)\rightarrow Hom(H_{i}(X; A), G)\rightarrow 0$$
where $G$ is an $A$ module. In the case $G=\mathbb{Q}$ and $A=\mathbb{Q}$ the $Ext^1$ terms vanish (easy exercise). That means that
$$H^{i}(X; \mathbb{Q})\cong Hom(H_i(X;\mathbb{Q}), \mathbb{Q})$$
so inducing an isomorphism in rational cohomology directly translates to inducing an isomorphism between $Hom(H_i(X;\mathbb{Q}), \mathbb{Q})$ and $Hom(H_i(Y;\mathbb{Q}), \mathbb{Q})$.
If these two terms are isomorphic then applying $Hom(-, \mathbb{Q})$ yields isomorphic $\mathbb{Q}$-modules (a.k.a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space): $Hom(Hom(A, \mathbb{Q}), \mathbb{Q})$ is naturally isomorphic to $A$ and so following back the isomorphism (and using naturality) one obtains that $X\rightarrow Y$ induces isomorphisms in rational homology.

The natural isomorphism only holds if $A$ is finite-dimensional. However, even if it isn't, it's not hard to see that a linear map of vector spaces inducing an isomorphism on the double dual already has to have been an isomorphism.

You are completely right, thanks for the correction.

@AlessandroFenu Thank you!

@AlessandroFenu I've got a question. This is the version of the UCT that I know: "Let A be a PID. Given a chain complex $C$ of free A-modules and an A-module $G$ there is a short exact sequence $$ 0 \rightarrow \operatorname{Ext}\left(H_{q-1}(C;A), G\right) \rightarrow H^q(C, G) \xrightarrow{h} \operatorname{Hom}\left(H_q(C;A), G\right) \rightarrow 0 $$ and this sequence is split." So in our case $C=C_(X)$ and so  $A$ must be $\mathbb{Z}$. Why can you choose $A=\mathbb{Q}$? Is $C=C_(X)$ a $\mathbb{Q}$-module? Are you using a different version of UCT or mine is wrong?

@marc You can take $A=\mathbb{Q}$ and then $C=C_{*}(X)\otimes \mathbb{Q}$ (the usual -say- singular chain but with $\mathbb{Q}$ coefficients.) So now $C$ is a vector space at each degree and you can apply what was previously said

Alessandro has explained the UCT part of the argument but I want to explain the $\mathbb{Q}$-linear dual part a bit more carefully because there is a mild subtlety in it in the infinite-dimensional case. The claim at stake is the following:

Conservativity of the dual: Let $f : V \to W$ be a linear map between vector spaces (not necessarily finite-dimensional) over a field $K$. Then $f$ is an isomorphism if and only if the dual map $f^{\ast} : W^{\ast} \to V^{\ast}$ is an isomorphism.

Note that this is not true for modules over a non-field (e.g. over $\mathbb{Z}$), and that to apply it to the original claim about inducing isomorphisms in homology vs. cohomology we need to know that the identification $H^i(X, \mathbb{Q}) \cong H_i(X, \mathbb{Q})^{\ast}$ is natural (which is true since the UCT itself is natural).
Proof. In the finite-dimensional case, conservativity of the dual follows from the fact that the double dual of $V$ is naturally isomorphic to it, so if $f^{\ast}$ is an isomorphism then so is $(f^{\ast})^{\ast} \cong f$. In the infinite-dimensional case this is very far from true. But without taking the double dual, we can instead just argue that if $f^{\ast}$ is surjective then $f$ is injective and vice versa:

Taking contrapositives, if $f$ is not injective then $f(v) = 0$ for some nonzero $v \in V$. Then if $v^{\ast} \in V^{\ast}$ is any linear functional such that $v^{\ast}(v) = 1$ (which exists assuming the axiom of choice!), it follows that $\text{im}(f^{\ast})$ does not contain $v^{\ast}$, so $f^{\ast}$ is not surjective.
Again taking contrapositives, if $f$ is not surjective then $W/\text{im}(f)$ is nonzero. Then if $w^{\ast} \in W^{\ast}$ is any linear functional which vanishes on $\text{im}(f)$ (equivalently, any linear functional on $W/\text{im}(f)$) but which does not vanish identically (which, again, exists assuming the axiom of choice!), it follows that $f^{\ast}(w^{\ast}) = 0$, so $f^{\ast}$ is not injective.

We conclude that if $f^{\ast}$ is an isomorphism then $f$ is both injective and surjective, hence an isomorphism. $\Box$
Now for the
Mild subtlety: In both arguments we needed to know that vector spaces have "enough linear functionals": the key fact we need is that linear functionals separate points in the sense that if $v \in V$ is nonzero then there exists a linear functional $v^{\ast} \in V^{\ast}$ which does not vanish on it (which one might call the "algebraic Hahn-Banach theorem"). This is obvious in the finite-dimensional case by extending $v$ to a basis, and it continues to be true in the infinite-dimensional case for the same reason, but now we need the axiom of choice to extend $v$ to a basis.
In the absence of the axiom of choice this can fail badly, and it can happen that the $\mathbb{Q}$-linear dual of a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space is zero! ($\mathbb{R}$ is an example.) This would make the desired statement no longer true, if we take very strange examples for $X$ such as Eilenberg-MacLane spaces $K(\mathbb{R}, 1)$.
Fortunately I don't think this really affects the intended application. First of all I think all of the rational homology in the intended application is finite-dimensional. But even if it weren't, if the spaces involved have reasonable CW decompositions then one ought to be able to write down more-or-less explicit bases of rational homology using cells even in the infinite-dimensional case and then I think there's no problem.

Why Hahn Banach? The continuous dual spaces are surely not relevant here, and with the algebraic dual spaces this is trivial by just fiddling with a Hamel basis

@FShrike: it was in quotes for a reason. I just mean this is the "algebraic analogue" of Hahn-Banach. And the entire point of the discussion was that the existence of Hamel bases is independent of ZF and requires the axiom of choice. So I don't consider this an entirely trivial fact and it deserves some discussion in my opinion.

(The general point here is that it would be deeply silly if the axiom of choice were needed to prove Serre's finiteness theorem, which is the result the OP is trying to understand.)

Topology and homological algebra without choice seems like asking for trouble… but ok, I was mostly just checking we don’t need continuous duals. Since $(-)^\ast$ is suitably ambiguous (some use # for algebraic duals) maybe it’s worth clarifying

That's a fair point, I added a clarification to the language. Do you think any of the fundamental calculations in algebraic topology depend on choice? I am extremely confident that Serre's finiteness theorem holds in ZF even if the standard proof involves machinery that uses choice to construct projective resolutions or whatever.

I’m of the opinion that choiceless mathematics is interesting to study, and I mean no offence to set theorists, but also that choice is morally obvious and for the overwhelming majority of standard mathematics one should feel free to assume it and not bother to check - choice hasn’t been controversial for a while. For example, if submodules of free modules aren’t free, how the hell do you believe in basic results like UCT? (! this depends on the specific UCT, there are loads, but is relevant for singular (co)homology)

That's also a fair point. If nothing else, in the absence of choice the Ext term in the UCT could fail to vanish...
